# Select .button where data-source equals all

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes, jquery-filter

As mentioned in the question's title, I'm trying to select the `a.button` where `:data(source==all)` but with no success, here's what I've tried

```
$('.button:data("source==all")').css('background', 'red');
$('#sources-list li').find('.button:data("source==all")').css('background', 'red');
$('#sources-list li').find('.button:data("source=all")').css('background', 'red');
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
$('a.button[data-source=all]').css('background', 'red');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.button').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('source') == "all"
}).css('background', 'red');
```